# SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory (SQL: select * from `users` where `email` = test@test.com limit 1)

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5, vagrant

I made a new installation of laravel, I have a mysql which turns on the vagrant, I made the connection in the .env file and in the file config / database.php

i do not understand why i get this error, my system is linux and i use vagrant to host my sql

Can you help me to understand the problem ?

laravel error message
[image: laravel error message]

environment file laravel
[image: environment file laravel]

laravel config/database file
[image: laravel config/database file]

Answer (score 2):

If you have installed laravel just now, You should do :

`php artisan migrate`

It will install the migration and will create tables for you. one of which is `users` table which is used for authentication.

Answer (score 0):

if you have installed fresh laravel, than you should run `php artisan make:auth` and then run `php artisan migrate` this will populate table `users` in your connected database.

Answer (score 0):

`php artisan migrate` must work! and you go to `/register`

More info here: https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/authentication#introduction